# Can anyone suggest a calculation model for estimating the location of a dropped object falling from a height?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, projectile, simulations, drag, models

I'm trying to find models that allow me to calculate dropped objects, specifically, a model where I can consider lateral displacement due to wind force and vary the weight and resistance force of the object. This is crucial because I'm trying to calculate with utmost precision the point of impact of a tool falling from a height at a construction site, to determine the safety zone that must be established below to prevent injury to anyone. I appreciate any information in advance.

Comment: It isn't simple. See this - [Backspin Basketball Flies Off Dam](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2OSrvzNW9FE)

Answer (score 0):

If the fall time in vacuum is $T_V$ (calculable from $h=gT_V^2/2$) and the actual fall time is $T_A$ (can be measured for the appropriate tool) then the lateral displacement in a uniform sideways wind of speed $W$ is
$$
d= W(T_A-T_V).
$$
This follows from the fact that the same   drag force is responsible for  slowing  the falling object and for pushing it sideways.

Of course, on a building site the wind speed is likely to vary with height, so youy have to take the worst case with $W$ the maximum wind speed.